# git rollback to commit merge with previous commit and push it to the server

Tags: git

I have made a merge and push it to server. But I did not like how it was merged. I have rollback using this command:

```
git checkout 93efaa6d224b4a6240018e746e94c03a4cd4f8c7
```

But I have commit that I want to merge with my current state, that was made before commit `93efaa6d224b4a6240018e746e94c03a4cd4f8c7` by another user.

Right now terminal says: `HEAD detached from 93efaa6`

How can I make merge with another commit `41b9bd5` and move all these changes to the top of all commits.

[image]

So right now I am staying on **fixes** and want to merge with **Added build number autoincrement**. And then want to make push to the server.

Comment: Hang on a second.  Do you want to roll back to that commit, or do you want to discard *all* commits that occur after 41b9bd5?

Comment: @Makoto, I want to have all changes before merge commit as you can see on image. I have merged my code 93efaa6 with 41b9bd5 that is a commit by another developer. But when I merged it after that I did git checkout to 93efaa6 and then continued write code. Right now I have new changes and files in my 93efaa6 detached from head. I understand that it will be easiest just remove last commit from the server and make a reset. But right now I have new updates in detached 93efaa6 commit and I want to merge it with 41b9bd5 and then push to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To roll back your branch to that commit (and not just check it out for browsing or use as a starting point), use `git reset` (with `--hard` to also reset the working directory):

```
git reset --hard 93efaa6d224b4a6240018e746e94c03a4cd4f8c7
```

To push that, you’ll also need `git push -f`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can rollback your commit with git reset command (and all changes until that commit `93efaa` ) with `git reset --hard 93efaa6d224b4a6240018e746e94c03a4cd4f8c7`

- git reset is specifically about updating the index, moving the HEAD.
- git checkout is about updating the working tree (to the index or the specified tree). It will update the HEAD only if you checkout a branch (if not, you end up with a detached HEAD).

Than you can made new changer (if there is any and create new commit) and rebase your tree with  `git-rebase -i` (and merge all desired commits).

Comment: but I have alredy add some code to my 93efaa6d224b4a6240018e746e94c03a4cd4f8c7

Comment: Let's assume you're on top of the branch:

- `git reset --hard 93efaa6d224b4a6240018e746e94c03a4cd4f8c7`
- `git rebase -i HEAD~5`
first command discards your last commit called merge, second lunches editor where you can squash all necessary commits, after that you need to push to server with `git push -f`